# Adding encryption to a server built with SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, encryption, tls1.2

I've looked high and low and am quite surprised to find *absolutely nothing* that answers this question:

**How can one implement SSL/TLS (or similar) encryption when using `SocketAsyncEventArgs`?** I did read that one *could* theoretically use a `SslStream` and "cheat" by creating a go-between to coordinate data in and out of the stream, to and from the socket. That all seems ridiculous...

I Looked into BouncyCastle but they don't seem to have support for server-side encryption. Admittedly, the source for this info is almost 10 years old, but my own research turned up nothing.

I'm not interested in changing my server architecture, so please refrain from telling me "I don't really need the performance of `SocketAsyncEVentArgs` and should just change to `TcpListener`".

I'm interested in any method of implementing reliable encryption between client and server using `SocketAsyncEventArgs`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to attach SAEA to encryption. They don't share an API in common, so everything is bridges.

The easiest way to do this is - as you know - `SslStream`, but: that isn't usually compatible with `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. There are alternatives - I can think of at least 3 different ways of doing this with "pipelines", for example; but all of them would be a major architecture change from *naked* SAEA. So if the difference between SAEA and `SslStream` is too large, the difference between SAEA and `IDuplexPipe` is even larger. However, "pipelines" is *designed* for high scalable perf, so... maybe it'll suit your tastes anyway? I've blogged about pipelines *a lot* recently, if it would help; plus I have github examples of client/server code, including a 2.5M+ ops/second redis-like server.

Comment: I'll take a look at your blogs on pipelines. I've started to look into the RFC spec on TLS 1.2 and, although not trivial, I think it may be useful to implement the protocol using a library like BouncyCastle to do the (very) low level stuff.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart you might also want to ask Tim Seaward whether "Leto" will be supporting that; "Leto" is "OpenSSL meets pipelines"

Comment: @MatthewGoulart sure, it'll do; part 3 has lots more practical hands-on code that'll be more useful for real usage; but the emphasis to consider before jumping in: you still need a TLS piece; options 1) SslStream in the middle (I'm using NetworkStream=>SslStream=>pipelines); 2) "Leto" (Tim's thing); 3) "Kestrel" has a TLS wrapper; last time I asked David Fowler about this, he hinted that it isn't quite perfect for the socket mode yet, but : they're working on it

Comment: I appreciate the info. I'll take a look at all three options. After reading a few paragraphs it seems your blog will be my evening read for the next few nights.